# SignalR: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 (no reason given) called while in state Connected

Tags: c#, angular, iis, websocket, asp.net-core-signalr

How can i overcome this error? The way i use SignalR on client (Angular):

```
this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(environment.appUrl + '/api/hub/weatherforecast', {
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
        logMessageContent: true
      })
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
      .build();

    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log('SignalR connection started'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting SignalR connection: ' + err));

    this.hubConnection.onclose = (error) => {
      console.log('SignalR connection closing');
      console.log(error);
      window.location.reload();
    };
```

And on server:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<DeviceHub>("/api/hub/weatherforecast");
        });
```

Additionally i sniffed this traffic through WireShark:

[image]

1,3,5 requests addressed to server, 2 and 4 requests are sent from server. Logs from browser console:

```
[2024-03-04T11:16:23.996Z] Debug: Starting HubConnection.
[2024-03-04T11:16:23.996Z] Debug: Starting connection with transfer format 'Text'.
[2024-03-04T11:16:23.997Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) Connecting.
SignalR connection refreshing
SignalR listeners added successfully
[2024-03-04T11:16:24.015Z] Information: WebSocket connected to ws://192.168.1.100:31234/api/hub/weatherforecast.
[2024-03-04T11:16:24.015Z] Debug: The HttpConnection connected successfully.
[2024-03-04T11:16:24.015Z] Debug: Sending handshake request.
[2024-03-04T11:16:24.016Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 32. Content: '{"protocol":"json","version":1}'.
[2024-03-04T11:16:24.016Z] Information: Using HubProtocol 'json'.
[2024-03-04T11:16:24.029Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) data received. String data of length 3. Content: '{}'.
[2024-03-04T11:16:24.030Z] Debug: Server handshake complete.
[2024-03-04T11:16:24.030Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 11. Content: '{"type":6}'.
[2024-03-04T11:16:24.030Z] Debug: HubConnection connected successfully.
SignalR connection started
[2024-03-04T11:16:26.111Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) socket closed.
[2024-03-04T11:16:26.111Z] Debug: HttpConnection.stopConnection(Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 (no reason given).) called while in state Connected.
[2024-03-04T11:16:26.112Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 (no reason given).'.
[2024-03-04T11:16:26.112Z] Debug: HubConnection.connectionClosed(Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 (no reason given).) called while in state Connected.
```

WebSockets are enabled in IIS, and my server is running correctly in debug, but when deployed on IIS, it cause this error. It literally connecting for a second and the next throws an error. It feels like something else is trying to end connection, because in server logs there are nothing special can be found:

```
04-03-2024 | 16:28:10.802 | INFO | Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://192.168.1.100:31234/api/hub/weatherforecast - -
04-03-2024 | 16:28:10.802 | DEBUG | The request path  does not match the path filter
04-03-2024 | 16:28:10.802 | DEBUG | 1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/api/hub/weatherforecast'
04-03-2024 | 16:28:10.802 | DEBUG | Request matched endpoint '/api/hub/weatherforecast'
04-03-2024 | 16:28:10.802 | DEBUG | The request has an origin header: 'http://localhost:5000'.
04-03-2024 | 16:28:10.802 | INFO | CORS policy execution successful.
04-03-2024 | 16:28:10.802 | INFO | Executing endpoint '/api/hub/weatherforecast'
04-03-2024 | 16:28:10.802 | DEBUG | New connection Fx_ljUj6zb5j2umX9pJeCQ created.
04-03-2024 | 16:28:10.802 | DEBUG | Establishing new connection.
04-03-2024 | 16:28:10.817 | DEBUG | OnConnectedAsync started.
04-03-2024 | 16:28:10.817 | DEBUG | Socket opened using Sub-Protocol: '(null)'.
04-03-2024 | 16:28:10.830 | DEBUG | Found protocol implementation for requested protocol: json.
04-03-2024 | 16:28:10.830 | DEBUG | Completed connection handshake. Using HubProtocol 'json'.
```

That's all. Client knows that something went wrong but cant describe anything, and server does not know anything about error. I've watched for proxy setting - there are none, nor VPN settings were used. What can i else watch for to determine the source of the problem and maybe how can i solve it?

Comment: The timestamps of the provided logs are inconsistent, which does not make any sense. Please provide more log information, and please [enable EnableDetailedErrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options).

Comment: @JasonPan there goes the fire: EnableDetailedErrors already turned on. There are just no exceptions from hub on ASP.NET server. I've taken two similiar logs from identic situations, you can substract 4 minutes and add 14 seconds to the bottom logs, this will give you nothing.

Comment: Also, if i add custom ```public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)``` to the hub and try to write exception from it to separate file, for an example, "C:\log.txt", it will not produce any files. One can conclude that there are no exception at all at server side.

Comment: Hi RelativeLayouter, could you share a minimal sample project which can reproduce the issue, I can help you to fix it. And please don't forget to hide your sensitive information.